# String columns giving column is not iterable error for instr operation in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
#Approach 1:

from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length, upper, instr, when, col

df.select(
    '*',
    when(instr(col('expc_featr_sict_id'), upper(col('sub_prod_underscored'))) > 0,
         substring(col('expc_featr_sict_id'),
                   (instr(col('expc_featr_sict_id'), upper(col('sub_prod_underscored'))) + length(col('sub_prod_underscored')) + 1))
         .otherwise(substring(col('expc_featr_sict_id'), length(col('expc_featr_sict_id')) - 6, length(col('expc_featr_sict_id'))))
         .alias('design_form_factor_temp')
).show()

##Approach 2

df2 = (df.select(f.col('*')).withColumn('design_form_factor_temp',

f.when(f.instr(f.col('expc_featr_sict_id'), f.upper(f.col('sub_prod_underscored')))›6, f.substring(f.col('expc_featr_sict_id'), (f.instr(f.col ('expe_featr_sict_id'), f.upper (f.col('sub_prod_underscored'))) + f.length(f.col('sub_prod_underscored'))+ 1)).otherwise(f.substring(f.col('expc_featr_sict_id'),(f.length(f.col('expc_featr_sict_id')))-6),(f.length(f.col('expc_featr_sict_id'))))
```

columns `expc_featr_sict_id` and `sub_prod_underscored` contains string value.

I am getting error for below line. it's giving Column is not iterable.

`when(instr(col('expc_featr_sict_id'), upper(col('sub_prod_underscored'))) > 0,`

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example please?

Comment: please use this code `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([('ABCDEF','CDEF'),('BCDEF' , 'DEFG'),('CDEFGH','DEFGH'),('DEFGHI' ,'EFGHI'),('ABCDEFGHIJ' ,'CDEFABC')],['expc_featr_sict_id'  , 'sub_prod_underscored'])
df.show()`

Comment: And what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your second argument can't be a column, it must be a string, [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.instr.html#pyspark.sql.functions.instr)

Comment: Okay How can I make each value of column iterable.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that `instr` works with a column and a string literal:

> `pyspark.sql.functions.instr(str: ColumnOrName, substr: str) → pyspark.sql.column.Column`

You will also have a problem with `substring` that works with a column and two integer literals

> `pyspark.sql.functions.substring(str: ColumnOrName, pos: int, len: int) → pyspark.sql.column.Column`

Data generation as in your comment:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f from pyspark.sql import types as t
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('ABCDEF', 'CDEF'),('BCDEF', 'DEFG'), ('CDEFGH', 'DEFGH'),
                        ('DEFGHI', 'EFGHI'), ('ABCDEFGHIJ', 'CDEFABC')],
    ['expc_featr_sict_id'  , 'sub_prod_underscored']
)
```

The following code reproduces your error `TypeError: Column is not iterable`

```py
df.withColumn("test",
    f.instr(f.col('expc_featr_sict_id'), f.upper(f.col('sub_prod_underscored')))
).show()
```

In scala the error is more explicit than in python.

```
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
 required: String
       Seq(("abcd", "b")).toDF("a", "b").withColumn("test", instr($"a", $"b")).show
                                                                        ^
```

The problem is that spark does not allow a column expression as a second parameter of `instr`. However, the sql expressions are usually more permissive in spark. You can overcome this limitation with `expr`:

```py
df.withColumn("test", f.expr("instr(expc_featr_sict_id, upper(sub_prod_underscored))")).show()
```

```
+------------------+--------------------+----+
|expc_featr_sict_id|sub_prod_underscored|test|
+------------------+--------------------+----+
|            ABCDEF|                CDEF|   3|
|             BCDEF|                DEFG|   0|
|            CDEFGH|               DEFGH|   2|
|            DEFGHI|               EFGHI|   2|
|        ABCDEFGHIJ|             CDEFABC|   0|
+------------------+--------------------+----+
```

I am unsure of what you are trying to do here but if you wrap the calls to `instr` and `substring` inside of an `expr`, you should fix your error. You also seem to use `substring` with only one index (the first call). That is also impossible in spark. You always need to specify the start and end indices.

Here is an example of a combination of `instr` and `substring` to obtain the string of `expc_featr_sict_id` that comes before the matching `sub_prod_underscored`:

```py
df.withColumn("test",
    f.expr("substring(expc_featr_sict_id, 0, instr(expc_featr_sict_id, upper(sub_prod_underscored))-1)")
).show()
```

```
+------------------+--------------------+----+
|expc_featr_sict_id|sub_prod_underscored|test|
+------------------+--------------------+----+
|            ABCDEF|                CDEF|  AB|
|             BCDEF|                DEFG|    |
|            CDEFGH|               DEFGH|   C|
|            DEFGHI|               EFGHI|   D|
|        ABCDEFGHIJ|             CDEFABC|    |
+------------------+--------------------+----+
```